# Candlestick bodies are limited to Zero?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-studio

[image]

```
$csv= Import-Csv -Path "path\Collected.csv" | sort InstanceMarket
   
   
    $high = $csv.'Maximum Runup'
    $low = $csv.'Maximum Drawdown'
    $open = "0"
    $close = $csv.'Daily Profit/Loss'
    $vol = $csv.'Today Total Trades'
   
   
   
    [void]$chart1.Series.Add("high")
    $chart1.Series["high"].ChartType = 'candlestick'
    $chart1.Series["high"].BorderWidth = 5
    $chart1.Series["high"].Color = 'Black'
    $csv| ForEach-Object { $chart1.Series["high"].Points.addxy($_.'InstanceMarket', $_.'Maximum Runup') }
   
    [void]$chart1.Series.Add("low")
    $chart1.Series["low"].ChartType = "candlestick"
    $chart1.Series["low"].BorderWidth = 5
    $chart1.Series["low"].Color = 'Black'
    $csv| ForEach-Object { $chart1.Series["low"].Points.addxy($_.'InstanceMarket', $_.'Maximum Drawdown') }
 
   
    [void]$chart1.Series.Add("open")
    $chart1.Series["open"].ChartType = "candlestick"
    $chart1.Series["open"].BorderWidth = 5
    $chart1.Series["open"].Color = 'orange'
    $csv| ForEach-Object { $chart1.Series["open"].Points.addy($open) }
   
   
    [void]$chart1.Series.Add("Closepnl")
    $chart1.Series["Closepnl"].ChartType = "candlestick"
    $chart1.Series["Closepnl"].BorderWidth = 10
    $chart1.Series["Closepnl"].BorderDashStyle = 'Solid'
    $chart1.Series["Closepnl"].BorderColor = 'GreenYellow' #test
    $csv| ForEach-Object { $chart1.Series["Closepnl"].Points.addxy($_.'InstanceMarket', $_.'Daily Profit/Loss') }
   
   
    $points = $Chart1.Series["high"].Points
   
    ForEach ($series in $points)
    {
        #Work in progress for Currency format
        $series.LabelFormat = -f "{0:C0}"
        $series.Label = $series.YValues
       
    }
   
    #######
    $points = $Chart1.Series["Closepnl"].Points
   
    ForEach ($series in $points)
    {
       
        if ($series.YValues -gt 0)
        {
            $Series.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(0, 119, 178)
        }
        else
        {
            $Series.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(138, 12, 19)
        }
       
    update-Chart $chart1 -XPoints $csv.'InstanceMarket' -YPoints $highmark, $lowmark, $openmark, $close -ChartType Candlestick
```

What am I missing to make these look like normal candlesticks? The greenyellow lines doesn't make sense to me? I made them Greenyellow to try and tell what is going on. Why are they much larger horizontally and rest of candle is smaller? The wicks look correct.

Im also trying to format the labels. What is the syntax of formats?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.